# How to pass Scala DataSet to Java Class in Apache Flink

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I am new in Scala. So I want to process the DataSet of Apache Flink in Java. But I have a DataSet in Scala code that I want to pass in a methods of Java Class. 
For example:
In Scala:

```
val dS: DataSet[Vector] = ...
SampleJavaClass.sendDS(ds)
```

In SampleJavaClass.java there is a method like `sendDs(DataSet<Vector> javaDs)`

I am trying to do this but show error message:
type mismatch; found :

> org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[org.apache.flink.ml.math.Vector]
>   required:   org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment Error
>   occurred in an application involving default arguments.

How can I solve this problems. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scala `DataSet` is indeed a wrapper around the Java `DataSet`. However, since the method `javaSet` is package private, you cannot access it. Thus, there is currently only a very hacky way to convert a Scala `DataSet` to a Java `DataSet`.

In order to access the `javaSet` method, you have to define your package to be a sub-package of `org.apache.flink`. This is, admittedly, not best practice, though.

If this is a feature which is strictly required, you should file a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/) for it.

Comment: I have one package of scala files: (package org.apache.flink.quickstart). Do I need to create (package org.apache.flink.quickstart.java) for the java files? Then I can send scala DS to Java DS?

Comment: The file in which you call `javaSet` has to be in a `org.apache.flink` package. Thus, you could write yourself a helper function which lives in a `org.apache.flink` package and simply calls the `javaSet` method for a given `DataSet`.

Comment: But without function, it is not working. Why? what is the hack here. Could you please explain if possible?

Comment: What do you mean with without function it is not working? The problem is that the `DataSet.javaSet` method is declared as `private[flink]` which means that it can only be accessed by code which resides in a `org.apache.flink` or sub package. Usually you should define your own package names to avoid name conflicts, but here it's the only way to access the `javaSet` function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two DataSet classes in Flink a [java one](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/api/scala/DataSet.html)
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/api/scala/DataSet.html   and a [scala one](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/api/scala/DataSet.html). You can access the java one from the underlying scala DataSet via javaSet().

I would try to

```
SampleJavaClass.sendDS(ds.javaSet())
```

that might appease your code.

Comment: I have tried this approach. But It is showing the above error I mentioned. (Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.) What does it mean?